# Accordion in Flex 4.5 Mobile App

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, accordion, flex4.5

I want to work on text layout to display in a vertical accordion. I was able to work with accordion in web app but unable to work on a mobile app since the accordion is not available in mobile flex. Please help me to work on flex mobile accordion. Also suggest me how to display the paragraph contents and bulletins in flex mobile accordion...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Application tabs for mobile solutions:

http://devgirl.org/2011/05/09/styling-the-flex-4-5-mobile-application-tabs-and-actionbar/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:ViewNavigator id="trends" label="Trends" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TrendsView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="attach" label="Attach" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.AttachView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="call" label="Call Center" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.CallView"/>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```