# Accordion in Flex 4.6 Mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm new to Flex Mobile application development.

I want to create the Accordion in Flex Mobile application. We can not use the MX:Accordion component in Flex Mobile application.

This question is possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252674/flex-accordion-component-in-mobile-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983221/accordion-in-flex-4-5-mobile-app).  But both are helpless.

[image] 
This is what I need.

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom accordion layout for instance.

Check out this page for example and usage: http://www.tink.ws/blog/accordionlayout/.

The source code for the layout itself can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/tink/source/browse/trunk/flex4.5/spark/src/ws/tink/spark/layouts/AccordionLayout.as